# Flink jon on Yarn cluster

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a Flink job on YARN on my mac. For this I did the following

1 Downloaded Hadoop which comes with YARN and updated the classpaths
2 Downloaded Flink and cd into /Users//flink-1.16.1/bin
3 executed

```
./bin/flink run-application -t yarn-application \
-Djobmanager.memory.process.size=2048m \
-Dtaskmanager.memory.process.size=4096m \
./examples/batch/WordCount.jar
```

but i am getting following output where its continously trying to connect to resource manager

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/vasu/flink-1.16.1/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.4/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2023-04-27 12:21:04,214 WARN  org.apache.flink.yarn.configuration.YarnLogConfigUtil        [] - The configuration directory ('/Users/vasu/flink-1.16.1/conf') already contains a LOG4J config file.If you want to use logback, then please delete or rename the log configuration file.
2023-04-27 12:21:04,246 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider [] - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2023-04-27 12:21:04,331 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor                  [] - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
2023-04-27 12:21:06,464 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client                                 [] - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2023-04-27 12:21:08,472 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client                                 [] - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2023-04-27 12:21:10,481 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client                                 [] - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2023-04-27 12:21:12,487 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client                                 [] - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2023-04-27 12:21:14,496 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client                                 [] - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2023-04-27 12:21:16,505 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client                                 [] - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)

Answer (score 0):

I added below and now yarn top is able to connect to resource manager but yarn top gives this output reporting 1 unhealthy
NodeManager(s): 1 total, 0 active, 1 unhealthy, 0 decommissioned, 0 lost, 0 rebooted

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1</value>
</property>
```